# Stop .NET Firebird (2.6.5) provider writing all SQL to console

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, logging, console, firebird

The new .NET Firebird provider is writing ALL SQL to the console which slows down the execution of our program in Visual Studio. We use NHibernate and monitor all SQL commands using NHibernate Profiler.

Here is a link to the new logging feature in the .NET provider;
http://blog.cincura.net/232387-improved-command-logging-in-ado-net-provider-for-firebird/

Is there any way we can disable the logging of SQL to the console but still retain all other logging?

Using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 2):

You can see the solution in [follow up post](http://blog.cincura.net/232603-improved-command-logging-in-ado-net-provider-for-firebird-part-2/). Basically just remove all listeners (Visual Studio attached by default the one that put messages into Output Window).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered recompiling the source code?

If so look for the method LogCommand in FBCommand.cs